# How to tell if the ArcGIS10.3 Image server extension is installed and activated?

Tags: extensions, image-service

Most extensions within ArcGIS can be activated over the extensions dialog under Tools>extensions. With ArcGIS Server Image Extension I cannot see whether it is installed yet alone activated. I can publish image mosaics directly so it must be installed is some form. How can I confirm this? In  ArcGIS Server Manager under the Site tab the Software Authorization tab
shows no extensions. If I can publish an image mosaic directly as an image service from a registered FGDB, does this mean it has been installed correctly?

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS Server Manager go to the Site tab, then the Software Authorization tab.  That page will list any licensed extensions on your server.